# How to pass integers in a loop using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, stocks

I am trying to run the following code:

```
%% Getting Stocks
stocks = hist_stock_data('01012013','07112014','GDXJ', 'SPY','GOOGL', 'QQQ', 'AAPL');

%% Loop to get the stocks in order by date
while i <= 5

stocks(1,i).Date=datenum(stocks(1,i).Date); 
stocks(1,i).Date = stocks(1,i).Date(end:-1:1); 
stocks(1,i).AdjClose = stocks(1,i).AdjClose(end:-1:1); 
stocks(1,i).Ticker =stocks(1,i).AdjClose;
end
```

However I am getting the following error:

`Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

I have searched the web but do not really understand why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you must have mentioned that `hist_stock_data` is a function that you got from an external source and isn't a MATLAB builtin function or variable. Well, I googled for it and found it on [MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18458-historical-stock-data-downloader/content/hist_stock_data.m).

Next up looking at the code, here's some advice - Try to avoid using `i` as an iterator because when uninitialized MATLAB would consider it as the [imaginary unit](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/i.html). Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). That's why you were getting that error - `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`, because the index being used was the `imaginary unit` that can't be used as an index.

So, we could change `i` to something like `ii` -

```
while ii <= 2
    stocks(1,ii).Date=datenum(stocks(1,ii).Date);
    stocks(1,ii).Date = stocks(1,ii).Date(end:-1:1);
    stocks(1,ii).AdjClose = stocks(1,ii).AdjClose(end:-1:1);
    stocks(1,ii).Tiicker =stocks(1,ii).AdjClose;
end
```

Then, we run the code and see this error -

```
Undefined function or variable 'ii'.
```

Now, I made some guesswork and replaced that `while-loop` with a `for-loop` that iterates for all the elements in the struct `stocks`. So, it becomes -

```
for ii = 1:numel(stocks)
    stocks(1,ii).Date=datenum(stocks(1,ii).Date);
    stocks(1,ii).Date = stocks(1,ii).Date(end:-1:1);
    stocks(1,ii).AdjClose = stocks(1,ii).AdjClose(end:-1:1);
    stocks(1,ii).Tiicker =stocks(1,ii).AdjClose;
end
```

This runs fine, but make sure the results are what you were looking to have in `stocks`.

If you were looking to run the loop for the first `5` elements only, then do this -

```
for ii = 1:5
```